# Windows 10 & Internet Explorer 11 Wordpress passwords

Tags: passwords, internet-explorer

IE Saves passwords for all my Wordpress sites with one exception. Deleted the original settings in Credential Manager, username is saved but not the password.  Is this a Windows or Wordpress problem?

Comment: Website passwords are maintained at **Internet options > Content > Autocomplete settings** not in credential manager

Answer (score -3):

"Website passwords are maintained at **Internet options** > **Content** > **Autocomplete** settings not in credential manager – pun Dec 15 '15 at 6:09 "

Comment: So you just copied and pasted someone else's answer from the comments above?